# Cannot start Drupal

Tags: drush, chaos-tool-suite

I am getting this error from drush:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctools_include() in          /home/upgrade6/democratsabroad/drupal/sites/all/modules/contrib/message_notify/message_not ify.module on line 167

Call Stack:
    0.0005     169008   1. {main}() /usr/share/php/drush/drush.php:0
    0.0257    4517736   2. drush_main() /usr/share/php/drush/drush.php:14
    0.0879   11100240   3. _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch()    /usr/share/php/drush/drush.php:59
    0.1089   11108144   4. drush_bootstrap_to_phase() /usr/share/php/drush/drush.php:79
    0.5435   73935888   5. drush_bootstrap() /usr/share/php/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc:308
0.5440   73939144   6. _drush_bootstrap_drupal_login() /usr/share/php/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc:185
0.5442   73939560   7. drush_drupal_login() /usr/share/php/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc:945
0.5442   73939824   8. user_load() /usr/share/php/drush/includes/drupal.inc:138
0.5442   73940880   9. user_load_multiple() /home/upgrade6/democratsabroad/drupal/modules/user/user.module:366
0.5442   73941400  10. entity_load() /home/upgrade6/democratsabroad/drupal/modules/user/user.module:291
0.5442   73941928  11. entity_get_controller() /home/upgrade6/democratsabroad/drupal/includes/common.inc:7804
0.5442   73943096  12. entity_get_info() /home/upgrade6/democratsabroad/drupal/includes/common.inc:7835
0.5576   75414672  13. drupal_alter() /home/upgrade6/democratsabroad/drupal/includes/common.inc:7674
0.5596   75472128  14. message_notify_entity_info_alter() /home/upgrade6/democratsabroad/drupal/includes/module.inc:1101
0.5596   75472264  15. message_notify_get_notifiers() /home/upgrade6/democratsabroad/drupal/sites/all/modules/contrib/message_notify/message_notify.module:73
```

I tried reinstalling ctools but cannot enable it.

Comment: Can you provide details of what you did to get this errors ? What Drush Version are you running ? What Drupal version are you running and what version of ctools you are using ? When you try it out re-installing ctools did you remove the database by uninstalling the module.

Comment: The error comes from a file in message_notify, so I doubt this is related to either Drush or cTools. Try disabling message_notify by setting `status` to `0` in SQL `system` table.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have updated your site from previous version and this module was not included in this update. Please follow [**`this`**](https://www.drupal.org/node/1972302#comment-7336124) link to get possible solutions.